# Cleaning up alternating code

Tags: c#

I have this function that about the following

```
bool flag = true;
while(true){
    if(flag){
      function1();
    }else{
      function2();
    }
    flag = !flag;
}
```

I'm looking at it and it doesn't really seem that clean. I just want to alternate between those 2 functions. Is there a way to make this a bit more cleaner and more readable or would you just keep it this way? Because now I'm having like 5 rows of code that seems a bit messy.

PS: *The `while(true)` isn't actually part of the code, just a demonstration that it's going on for some time.*

Comment: I assume, `bool flag = true` is meant to be outside the for loop?

Comment: the way your example is written flag is always true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, it is ok. It's clear what is meant.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the state pattern. Although it's probably over kill for something so simple.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Answer (score 1):

Found this just now: adding answer (seems to be better than editing when new info is introduced since OP will be notified).

```
public IEnumerable<bool> AlternatingBools() {
  bool cur = false;
  while (true) {
    yield return cur;
    cur = !cur;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make something like a C# eqiv. of JQuery's toggle, using lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

It's disappointing that you can't just write:

```
(flag) ? function1() : function2();
```

But that's not valid.

If `function1` and `function2` return the same type, you could write:

```
var trash = (flag) ? function1() : function2();
```

Whether that's more readable is questionable.

And, of course, there's the option of putting everything on a single line:

```
if (flag) function1(); else function2();
```

Again, readability is questionable.  If that kind of thing is pervasive in your code, then one could argue that it's a common enough idiom.  But in general I would discourage something like that in a code review.

Again, if it's pervasive in your code you could write a method to handle it for you:

```
bool IfTrueFalseToggle(bool flag, Action trueFunc, Action falseFunc)
{
    if (flag)
        trueFunc();
    else
        falseFunc();
    return !flag;
}
```

And then you'd call it with:

```
flag = IfTrueFalseToggle(flag, function1, function2);
```

It probably needs a better name, and I wouldn't go that route unless I had lots of code that used it.  Plus, you'd probably end up having to write a zillion different similar methods to handle all the different types of `Action` or `Func` you'd want to call with it.

All things considered, I'd say that in general what you have is about as clean as it's going to get.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
bool flag = true;
while (true)
{              
        // xor operator        
        if (flag ^= true)
        {
              function1();
        }
        else
        {
              function2();
        }

}
```

Comment: Yeah I'd like that. I know it's the xor operator. But I'm not sure it improves any usability since people might easily read over it.